# Apply own function to every item in DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I have created a function to give out a rank based on the value in each cell of the table below:
Table name is "ranked"

```
Date        MMM     AOS     ABT
2016-01-31  55.0    411.0   102.0
2016-02-29  44.0    425.0   96.0
2016-03-31  29.0    410.0   70.0
2016-04-30  29.0    425.0   87.0
2016-05-31  46.0    409.0   52.0
```

Function:

```
def get_rank(x):
    if 1 <= x < 96:
        return 1
    elif 96 <= x < 193:
        return 2
    elif 193 <= x < 289:
        return 3
    elif 289 <= x <= 385:
        return 4
    elif x > 385:
        return 5
```

I have tried to apply the function using lambda:

```
ranked.apply(lambda x: get_rank(x))
```

However it gives me the error message:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The end goal is to have a 1 for all values in the table that are below 96, a 2 for all values higher than 192 and smaller than 289 .... and so on up to 5.

Could you please give me a hint how I can easily apply this function to the table?
Appreciate your help!

Comment: Which column you want to compare against?

Comment: I don't want to compare it to any column, just iterate over every item in each of the three columns. Then apply a value between 1-5 depending on the current value in the cell. So the first value for the column "MMM" should be 1. First value of "AOS" should be 5. Second value "ABT" should be 2.
You know what I mean?

Comment: Ahh ok. And you want to replace the original values in the DataFrame?

Comment: You want to use [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) instead:

```py
>>> ranked[['MMM','AOS','ABT']].applymap(get_rank)
```

Should return the sub-dataframe "MMM, AOS, ABT" resulting from applying your `get_rank()` function to each value.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add ranked columns to the data frame:

```
df['Ranked MMM']=[get_rank(i) for i in df['MMM']]
```

And also add a default return at the end of the function like return 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to do this. You don't have to wrap your function in a `lambda` since it already takes a single value as an argument. Since, trying to apply your function on the date would result in an error, you have to specify which columns you want to map on and then replace the original values.

```
apply_on = ["MMM", "AOS", "ABT"]
ranked[apply_on] = ranked[apply_on].applymap(get_rank)
```